# How to specify current mailbox Sent Items folder when cancelling .PickFolder dialog in Outlook 2016?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a VBA script to prompt for folder selection when sending an email. When you click "Cancel" on the folder list dialog Outlook crashes.

I would like, should I click "Cancel" the email copy is saved to the "Sent Items" folder. How do I specify a folder name for the current mailbox?

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
  Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
    If TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing" And _
      IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) Then
        Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
    ElseIf TypeName(objFolder) = "Nothing" Then
        'Attempt to specify folder for cancelled
        Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = "Sent Items"
    End If
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function IsInDefaultStore(objOL As Object) As Boolean
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Select Case objOL.Class
        Case olFolder
            If objOL.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                IsInDefaultStore = True
            End If
        Case olAppointment, olContact, olDistributionList, _
          olJournal, olMail, olNote, olPost, olTask
            If objOL.Parent.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
            IsInDefaultStore = True
        End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "This function isn't designed to work " & _
              "with " & TypeName(objOL) & _
              " items and will return False.", _
              , "IsInDefaultStore"
    End Select
    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
End Function
```

Based on my experience with other programming, I should be able to detect the "Cancel" button has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not "short-circuit" the `And` evaluation - it evaluates both parts of the test and then compares the results

```
If TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing" And IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) Then
```

Even if `TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing"` is False, it will still test `IsInDefaultStore(objFolder)`, so you need to put those into two separate tests.

```vb
  Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
  If TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing" Then
      If IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) Then 
          Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
      End If
  Else
      Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = "Sent Items"
  End If
```

Note it's more typical in VBA to use `If obj Is Nothing` than to test for `If TypeName(obj) = "Nothing"`

Comment: I tried the changes suggested and I am receiving the Run-time error '424: Object required. If I comment out the Else and SaveSentMessageFolder, it does not crash Outlook and the Object required error is not shown again...

Comment: Adding Else
      Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = "Sent Items"
The error message does not seem to give a line number. I base this finding on the old "add remove till it breaks" process.